# MergeSort Values outputting wrong

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a mergesort on a 100 size LinkedList, and after doing a lot of reading and comparisons, it seems that I have the algorithm right, but it just outputs the wrong stuff.  Code below

```
public class MergeSort 
{
static LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
public static void main(String[] args)
{        
    //add ints to list
    for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++)
    {
        list.add(roll());
    }
    //print list as a table
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i) + "\t");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(list.get(i) + "\t");
        }
    }
    mergeSort(list);

    //put some space between printed tables
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");

    //print list after sort
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if((i + 1) % 10 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(list.get(i) + "\t");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print(list.get(i) + "\t");
        }
    }
}
/*
Performs the mergesort
*/
static void mergeSort(LinkedList<Integer> ll)
{
    if(ll.size() > 1)
    {
        int tmp = ll.size() / 2;

        //this whole bit is to change the sublist of List type to a LinkedList
        List leftTmp = ll.subList(0, tmp);
        List rightTmp = ll.subList(tmp, ll.size());

        LinkedList<Integer> left = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Integer> right = new LinkedList<>();

        left.addAll(leftTmp);
        right.addAll(rightTmp);

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);

        merge(ll, left, right);
    }
}
//performs the merge on the sublists from mergeSort
static void merge(LinkedList<Integer> o, LinkedList<Integer> l, LinkedList<Integer> r)
{
    int combo = l.size() + r.size();

    int t = 0;
    int tL = 0;
    int tR = 0;

    while(t < combo)
    {
        if((tL < l.size() && tR < r.size()))
        {
            if(l.get(tL) < r.get(tR))
            {
                o.set(t, tL);
                t++;
                tL++;
            }
            else
            {
                o.set(t, tR);
                t++;
                tR++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(tL >= l.size())
            {
                while(tR < r.size())
                {
                    o.set(t, tR);
                    t++;
                    tR++;
                }
            }
            if(tR >= r.size())
            {
                while(tL < l.size())
                {
                    o.set(t, tL);
                    t++;
                    tL++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
/*
Performs a random roll for use in the list
Returns a random integer
*/
public static int roll()
{
    double d = Math.random() * 1000.0;
    int i = (int)d;
    return i;
}
}
```

It outputs this noise

```
642 495 716 307 716 893 681 617 150 761 
350 87  564 566 301 40  951 350 804 961 
406 864 161 408 600 434 218 142 808 426 
623 77  935 370 924 881 615 193 518 798 
955 479 810 778 901 375 656 103 526 583 
352 459 768 839 925 885 267 443 497 65  
982 688 812 227 242 479 819 271 681 48  
364 844 315 438 623 781 649 332 918 690 
275 891 927 516 897 504 127 581 111 704 
492 942 525 110 102 915 33  881 331 256 


0   0   1   2   3   1   2   3   4   5   
4   5   6   7   6   7   8   8   9   9   
10  10  11  12  13  14  15  11  12  13  
14  15  16  17  16  17  18  18  19  19  
20  21  22  23  20  21  22  23  24  25  
24  25  26  26  27  28  29  27  28  29  
30  30  31  32  33  31  32  33  34  35  
34  35  36  37  36  37  38  38  39  39  
40  40  41  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  
42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  48  49
```

Can anyone tell me why?  I've looked it over several times and can't figure it out.  It doesn't even have the same values, it changes them, and then KINDOF puts them in the right order.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: `tL` and `tR` are the indices, not the values.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `o.set(t, tL)`, you assign an index of the left list as a value of the merged list.
What you want to do is assign a value of the left list to the merged list - `o.set(t, l.get(tL))`.

That's why you got different numbers in the "sorted" list. You got indices instead of the original values.